# How to let the user set up his own contol scheme in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to offer the user the ability to choose what button is mapped to what action by *pressing* the button (you know, like in every game since the beggining of time.) rather than choosing it out of a drop-down. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what you want is not directly supported by unity - there is an official feature request - many developers want this: http://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/scripting-expose-input-manager-

Comment: you can create your own Input Manager - many developers do it like that

Comment: @JinJi. Yes! That sounds exactly like what I should do. Is there an article link you can provide on how to integrate it into unity?

Comment: you have 2 choices: #1 you can manipulate the existing one from unity: http://www.plyoung.com/blog/manipulating-input-manager-in-script.html or #2 stop using input manager from unity and make your own: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54063/inputmanager-in-unity (the basic idea is to use Input.GetKey() and Input.GetKeyDown() with a Dictionary<string,KeyCode> where string is the name of the action and KeyCode is the key that the user can change) or you can even use a Dictinary with lambda functions, see here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/54076